# Integration of a measurable function

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $\phi(x)$ be a **simple function**. If $a_1, a_2, . . . . , a_n$ are the distinct values taken by $\phi$ and $A_i = [x : \phi(x) = a_i]$, then

$\phi(x) =\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \Large {\chi}_{A_i}$ $(x)$ , where $\Large {\chi}_{A_i}$ is the step function.

My question is that is it possible that these $A_i$ are not disjoint?

Comment: $f$ is a function.

Comment: So only one-one and many-one mapping are possible. right? ($f$ and $\phi$ are same right?)

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in A_i\cap A_j$ with $i\ne j$. Then, by definition,
$a_i=\phi(x)$ and at the same time $a_j=\phi(x)$, which contradicts the condition that $a_i\ne a_j$ for $i\ne j$. Therefore, the sets $A_i$ are indeed disjoint.

Comment: well perhaps the last condition $a_i \neq a_j$ for $i \neq j$ is not given to us?

Comment: @Dark_Knight well, if we abandon the condition that $a_i$ are distinct, then, if $a_i=a_j$, you conclude that $A_i=A_j$ and therefore the formula you are trying to prove is false.